# HDMI to VGA converter not working on Hp laptop

Tags: laptop, display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I tried to connect to my Hp Laptop (HP Notebook - 15-db0101nl, windows 10) an old monitor (qdi, model 780) with a HDMI to VGA converter (ISNATCH is the brand).

my card is  an AMD Radeon(TM) R5 Graphics with a Graphics Processor 0x98E4

But on the monitor I tried to connect it only appearse the message : Mode not support  H:67.4 KHz V:60.0 Hz.
How can I get the two monitor to communicate?

Comment: What display resolution is set for the HDMI port? If the resolution is too high the **H**orizonal frequency is beyond what the monitor can handle. Try to reduce the resolution to reduce the **H** frequency. The vertical frequency at 60Hz is standard.

Comment: Thank you, for your help.The resolution written on the converter  is up to 1080P@60Hz. However changing my monitor resolution I were not able to solve the problem.

Comment: I can't find any specs online for the QDI 780 monitor nor the ISNATCH HDMI to VGA converter, but I have some generic advice that may help. Go to Settings > System > Display > Advanced display settings > Choose the external Display(2?) > Display adapter properties for Display(2?)" > List All Modes > pick "640 by 480, True Color (32 bit), 60 Hertz", click OK, then click "Apply". That's the lowest standard resolution that works with VGA and HDMI. If that works, you can try higher resolutions, but you cannot exceed the native resolution of the monitor unless the converter does active downscaling.